# Проблема с API вконтакта: redirect_uri is invalid

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю 2 запроса для авторизации (в первом получаю токен, во втором user ID), при втором получаю ошибку - `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"redirect_uri is invalid, please pass same redirect_uri, you used in authorize method."}`

Хотя, `redirect url` беру из одной и той же константы!!

В чем проблема может быть?

url типа - http://sub.site.com/login/?action=callback

Код:

class Vk extends Object {

```
public function getToken()
{
    header('Location: http://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id='.VK_APP_ID.'&scope='.VK_APP_PRIVACY.'&response_type=code&redirect_uri='.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/login/?action=callback');
    die();
}

public function getUserID($token)
{
    $data = self::curl("https://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/access_token?client_id=".VK_APP_ID."&client_secret=".VK_APP_SECRET."&code=".$token."&redirect_uri=".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/login/?action=callback");
    return json_decode($data);
}

public function curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

}
```

}

Собственно, для авторизации сначала использую 1 функцию: получаю токен, во второй его применяю. Ошибку возвращает 2ая функция

Comment: неплохо бы побольше сальных подробностей! : ) Фрагменты кода, там, лог запросов-ответов. Что за приложение: JS или сервер? выкладывайте, не стесняйтесь.

Comment: обновил :)

Comment: В [документации этого процесса авторизации](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) ВКОнтакты упоминают другой URL: `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize` — может, в этом дело?